# Is it possible to implement that an interrupted download can be continued on a server in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, browser, download

I have created a webapplication and set up an endpoint which returns a `FileStreamResult`, these can be large zip and pdf files for example. The main issue I'm facing is that if a download gets interrupted (for example the internet goes down by the client), the temporary file that is generated by the browser is immediately deleted.

I'm aware of `range-requests`, but to utilize them, I would have to read files from the client, to determine how much progress the download made, which is not possible from the server side and also, the same problem persists about the temporary file deletion.

So this seems like a browser limitation to me, but please correct me if I'm wrong, I would appreaciate any ideas.

Comment: You have to add Range:bytes=xxxxx-  in Request header to tell the size of the file you've already download, so that server could know where to continue,It's part of http.If you want save the position of pointer in server,have you considered how to figout the position belongs to which user? and how long  you want to keep it on the serverside?

Comment: Again, I have read about range requests. However, still, the procedure goes like this: The user clicks on the download => the browser starts the download, for example with chrome, it generates a temporary .crdownload file => if the download is interrupted, the temporary file is immediately deleted.

So there is no file remaining to check what has been already downloaded and still, I don't think I could read the temporary file even if it would have remained on the user's machine.

If this issue can't be addressed from the server side, I would happily use some front-end magic for this.